# Gradient Descentfor non-linear predictor?

Tags: gradient-descent

From I what I have read so far, if a loss function $\mathcal{l}(y,\hat{y})$ is convex where $\hat{y}$ is the (to be estimated) decision function, then gradient descent tries to minimizes the loss function w.r.t $\hat{y}$. This looks alright in theory but in practice of all algorithms I have seen assumes $\hat{y}$ to be linear function (and hence GD find the slope and intercept as as the optimization problem). My concern is what if I desire an non-linear predictor. How would I implement it in an algorithms?

Comment: You can apply Gradient Descent to any function $\hat{y}$ given that it has a derivative with respect to the parameter you want to optmize, theoretically. The convergence is dependent on few characteristics of the data and the function itself. What do you mean by non-linear?

Comment: Considering neural networks, the GD algorithm tries to minimize a non-linear loss function. The nonlinearity arises due to activation functions ( like sigmoid, tanh ) applied on the linear function `wx + b`.  Apart from NN, in linear regression, we use the MSE loss function, which indeed is non-linear. For a linear function, a minimum would not exist, as the gradient w.r.t to the parameter will be constant.